# Windows Server 2012: How to activate network discovery in GPO?

Tags: networking, group-policy, windows-server-2012, discovery

I use terminal-server Windows Server 2012 and I need to create a map drive GPO, but it doesn't take effect and I think it might be because I nee to activate  network discovery.

How to enable network discovery in GPO in Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling Network Discovery shouldn't have any affect on mapping network drives via a GPO.  It's more for "browsing" to a network share.

Regardless, if you want to enable it via GPO:

Computer Policy\Policies\Administrative Templates\Network\Link-Layer Topology Discovery.  There are two settings there:

[image]

The first setting allows the computer to find network resources such as file shares.  The second setting allows other computers to find this one.

Credit given to [James Summerlin](http://jamessummerlin.com/2012/07/08/using-group-policy-to-enable-network-discovery-in-a-domain/).

You may want to browse over this question as well, even though it states 2008 R2: [Cannot enable network discovery on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/69296/cannot-enable-network-discovery-on-windows-server-2008-r2?rq=1) -- it might give you better insight.

Comment: The way an answer should be.